# How to store 2D geometry vectors in std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, set

I've recently attended programming competition. One task was about geometry. Solution, that I invented was to use container of 2D vectors, where each vector is unique. The fastest container, which throws out copies is `std::unordered_set`. But I forgot how to make custom hash, so I used `std::set`:

```
struct Vector
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator<(const Vector& rhs) const
    {
        return x < rhs.x && y < rhs.y;
    }
}

std::set<Vector> geometry;
```

Of course it is wrong. **I understand why it is wrong**. It was one of six tasks in competition with time limit of 2 hours. So I assume, that this **task could be completed in ~20min**. I can use `std::vector` with check for uniquenes, but tester has time limit, and it can be slow(O(n^2)).

So I have these requirments:

1. **Container must prevent copies to be inserted**
2. **Container must be at least faster than `std::vector`**
3. **Code should be simple and small enough to write and debug it in ~10 minutes**

So, with all these requirments, how to store 2D vectors this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer pointed out, your solution is correct in theory.  However your `operator <` will not be correct.

An alternate to using `<complex>` is to just use a `std::pair` representing the x,y points.  The `std::pair` contains a built-in `operator <`, so all you need to do is call it in your `operator <` function.

See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct Vector
{
    std::pair<int, int> xy;
    Vector(int x_ = 0, int y_ = 0) : xy(std::make_pair(x_, y_)) {}
    bool operator<(const Vector& rhs) const
    { return xy < rhs.xy; }
};

std::set<Vector> geometry;

int main()
{
    geometry.insert(Vector(1,2));
    geometry.insert(Vector(1,5));
    geometry.insert(Vector(1, 8));
    geometry.insert(Vector(1, 8));
    geometry.insert(Vector(1, 8));  // repeated
    geometry.insert(Vector(1, 8));  // repeated
    geometry.insert(Vector(2, 2));

    std::cout << geometry.size();
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/njmuVX

That example shows that only unique items are stored in the set, showing that `std::pair` has the proper semantics required for `operator <`.

Given this, unless you are adding additional member functions to your `Vector` class, you could have simply done this:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> geometry;
```

And then do this in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    geometry.insert(make_pair(1,2));
    geometry.insert(make_pair(1, 5));
    geometry.insert(make_pair(1, 8));
    geometry.insert(make_pair(1, 8));
}
```

But again, do this if you know what the `pair` represents, and that you plan to not expand your `Vector` class to something more than x/y values.

Comment: `std::pair<T1,T2>::operator<()` uses for comparison only first value from pair, or not? If I remember right I will have problem, that (1,2) (1,5) (1,8) will  be considered the same.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha They are not the same if you use `std::pair` for the simple reason that pair(1,2) **is** different than pair(1,5) -- it's that simple.  Please try out the example, change the numbers, and you will see that the set will contain all of your values.  If you want further proof: http://ideone.com/njmuVX

Comment: @DoctorMoisha actually, this operator performs true lexicographic comparing, see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I believe that providing examples and saying that something *is simply different* from something does not prove anything. It may accidentally rely on implementation-dependent behavior, or something like that. Links to documentation/standard are a lot better argument.

Comment: @lisyarus The link I provided in my answer has that information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in fact, it does not, you have to follow one more link there :) I'm just saying that, probably, even the same link as an answer to that comment would be better, since your comment does not prove anything.

Comment: Well, if a user can't scroll down a half-page to see `operator <`, then what else can I say.

Answer (score 3):

I think your idea to store (let me say points) in an `std::set` is good and works well in practice.

But you have error in your implementation of `operator<()`. E.g. what happens for points

`(1, 4)` and `(2, 2)`? You code will tell that

`(1, 4) >=(2, 2)` and `(2, 2) >= (1, 4)`, which is definition for equality in stl

You can use `std::tie()` to automate such a comarision, like this:

```
struct Vector
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator<(const Vector& rhs) const
    {
        return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'll take a look on `bool std::complex<T>::operator<()`, thanks!

Comment: MSVC2013 compiler does not compile `std::set<std::complex<int> >` because `it does not defines proper operator<()`. Can you add working example?

Comment: @DoctorMoisha See my answer for a type that compares using `<`.

Comment: this answer is wrong so I'll fix it suggesting std::tie

Answer (score 1):

The point about ordering in a `std::set` is that some sort of ordering must exist but the ordering does not have to have any real meaning. The means that we are free to use any ordering provided that different pairs are never considered equal. A simple way of doing this is:

```
struct Vector
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator<(const Vector& rhs) const
    {
        if (x == x.rhs) {
            return y < rhs.y;
        else {
            return x < rhs.x;
        }
    }
}

std::set<Vector> geometry;
```

In the above, we will first sort on x and only if they are equal we will sort on y. This will provide the unique ordering needed for `stl::set`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::unordered_set` with a hasher of your choice. Also, do not forget overloading the `operator==` for uniqueness. To summarize it all,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Vector
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Vector(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) { }

    friend bool
        operator==(const Vector& lhs, const Vector& rhs)
        { return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y); }
};

struct Hash
{
    int operator()(const Vector& v)
    const { return (v.x + v.y) % 13; }
  //^^^^^
  //hasher functions must be const
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Vector, Hash> vectorset;

    vectorset.insert(Vector(0, 1)); //unique
    vectorset.insert(Vector(2, 1)); //unique
    vectorset.insert(Vector(3, 4)); //unqiue
    vectorset.insert(Vector(0, 1)); //repeat
    vectorset.insert(Vector(2, 1)); //repeat
    vectorset.insert(Vector(3, 4)); //repeat
    vectorset.insert(Vector(2, 1)); //repeat
    vectorset.insert(Vector(9, 4)); //unique
    vectorset.insert(Vector(2, 1)); //repeat

    std::cout << vectorset.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `4`